# Django join tables with ORM and conditional Where clause

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, django-orm

I have 4 tables to join; Personnels,Machines and Locations. I want to join these tables and add where clause to end of the ORM query if request body includes filtering data. Here is my models and raw query (I want to write this query in django ORM) and sample if condition for where clause;

Models ;

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    MachineId = models.ForeignKey(Machines,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='MachineId',related_name='%(class)s_Machine')
    PersonnelId = models.ForeignKey(Personnels,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='PersonnelId',related_name='%(class)s_Personnel')
    LocationId = models.ForeignKey(Locations,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='LocationId',related_name='%(class)s_Location')
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Sales"

class Machines(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Machines"

class Personnels(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Personnels"


class Locations(models.Model):
    Latitude = models.FloatField()
    Longitude = models.FloatField()
    LocationName = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Locations"
```

As you see I have 4 models. "Sales" table has foreignkeys to others. I want to get all informations in tables with using these foreign keys.(With Inner Join)

```
    query = '''select * from "Sales" as "SL" INNER JOIN "Personnels" as "PL" ON ("SL"."PersonnelId" = "PL"."user_id") INNER JOIN "Machines" as "MC" ON ("SL"."MachineId" = "MC"."id")    INNER JOIN "Locations" as "LC" ON ("SL"."LocationId" = "LC"."id") '''
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.data['personnel_name'] and request.data['personnel_name'] is not None:
            personnel_name = request.data['personnel_name']
            condition = '''WHERE "PL"."name" = '{0}' '''.format(personnel_name)
            query = query+condition
```

As it is seen, there are lots of quotes (if I don't write,postgresql makes some trouble) and code is not clean.

My question is, how can I write this query with using django ORM? As you see, I want to add where conditions dynamically. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should add your model code here. The general pattern is something like this. `Sales.objects.filter(personell__name=name)`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships It's not clear to me just from this code what exactly the relation between Location, Personell, Machine and Sale tables are, and which fields you want in the output.

Comment: You are right, I added my models.

Comment: Please describe your query in terms of what you want to accomplish in the plainest language possible (e.g "I want all locations with at least one machine") etc. It makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: I wrote a brief description.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use conventional naming, with only class names captilized, and model names singular.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`db_column` and `db_table` is useful if you have to connect the django app use an existing database. If not, django will create sensible table names by default. The table name can be different from the model field name.

To create a `join where`, use a [queryset filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
Sale.objects.filter(person__name='Jane Janes')
```

You might not need more joins, since django will perform additional queries when needed, but it can be achieved using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), and can give you better performance, since it reduces the total number of sql queries needed.

```
Sale.objects.filter(person__name='Jane Janes').select_related('machine', 'person', 'location')
```

It can be useful to inspect the actual SQL that will be performed when you evalute a queryset. You can do this by accessing the `QuerySet.query` property.

```
queryset = Sale.objects.select_related('machine').filter(
    person__name='Jim', location__name='London')

print(queryset.query)
```